# CSS classes for theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, css

Does anybody know predefined (suggested by WP) CSS classes which should I use in my theme?

I have seen somewhere in Internet a list of all CSS classes, which are used in WP theme, but can't find it.

**UPDATE:** I have found the site where I've seen this list: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/default-wordpress-generated-css-cheat-sheet-for-beginners/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many CSS classes generated by WordPress, depending on context.

The [Theme Review Guidelines](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review#WordPress-Generated_CSS_Classes) include the following, WordPress-generated CSS classes:

- Alignment Classes:

  - .aligncenter
  - .alignleft
  - .alignright
- Caption Related Classes:

  - .wp-caption
  - .wp-caption-text
  - .gallery-caption
- Post Classes:

  - .sticky
- Comment Classes:

  - .bypostauthor

Then, there are the body classes generated by [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class).

Then, there are the post classes generated by [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class).

Then, there are the comment classes generated by [`comment_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class).

Then, there are the menu item classes generated by [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes).

Comment: didn't you just finish rewriting sections of the Codex on this very subject? How timely!

Answer (score 7):

I found this list, which appears to be pretty comprehensive:

http://digwp.com/2010/05/default-wordpress-css-styles-hooks/

(I'm aware that an answer consisting of a link to an external site is discouraged, but not sure what else to do in this case?)

Comment: +1 copy/paste source wouldn't help as it would maybe exceed an _answer_.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe will be useful information from the Codex. [Styling List with CSS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Lists_with_CSS)