# Necessary css classes to be included in theme stylesheet

Tags: theme-development, css

Developing a WordPress theme. I've got two questions

1. Does the first response [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51135/css-classes-for-theme) hold true even after 5 years?
2. Is it necessary / considered a good practice to include all the
   default html tags, for example `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,acronym,abbr,code,pre,address` etc in my
   theme css file?

P.S: My aim is to publish the theme in wordpress.org. Even if they did allow me to publish it without the extra styling, I would like to know if it is a good practice to include it in any theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. So far, this is the most comprehensive list of all styling that theme might need for styling default widgets and other elements: [Default WP CSS classes for a theme](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/default-wordpress-generated-css-cheat-sheet-for-beginners/). You don't need to style all of them, but it is a good idea to use [Theme Checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/) plugin to scan your theme before submitting it to WordPress.org, because it should pick up all the things that you might be missing, including in CSS.
2. Your theme should have good typography, and that requires you define styling for all typography elements, like headings (h1...6), paragraph (p), blockquote, pre... If you don't do that, browsers fall to default styling for those elements, and your theme might look different in different browsers.

My suggestion is to start with some boilerplate stylesheet like [Normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) or some CSS/JS/HTML framework (like Foundation, but that might be an overkill, depending on your theme).

Comment: Thank you. That answers the second part. Please provide more information on the first one.

Comment: I have expanded my answer.